# Fail to decode the binary frame with Socket.IO Java when broadcasting for multiple clients

Tags: java, spring, websocket, socket.io, network-programming

On the server side, I create a room and add each SocketIoSocket into it, after that I broadcast a binary message to that room

```
SocketIoServer server = serverWrapper.getSocketIoServer();
SocketIoNamespace ns = server.namespace("/");
ns.on("connection", args12 -> {
    SocketIoSocket socket = (SocketIoSocket) args12[0];
    socket.joinRoom("ResetInterval");
    socket.on("message", arg -> {
       ns.broadcast("ResetInterval", "favorite-list", "Hi".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    })
})
```

Everything is okay for the first client but for the second one, I received a message said that the Packet that second client got was not binary, it was something like this:`{"\_placeholder":true,"num":0}` and throw error when I tried to decode it since it was in Json format. Here is my lines of code for client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = IO.socket("ws://localhost:9093");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket.on("favorite-list", objects -> {
        System.out.println("Receive msg: " + objects[0].toString());
    });

    socket.connect();

}
```

This was what I had for the first client
[image]

And the log what second client had:
[image]

I tried to google and even debug to find a solution but I got nothing so far

Comment: You're going to get better help if you post the error message verbatim and format it correctly as code

Comment: So you might need to type check since one is a string and the other is a byte array

Comment: I agree but as I read the code inside socket-io client, this library already took care of it @g00se

Comment: I don't know this library but you are doing: *after that I broadcast a binary message to that room*. You should probably only use `byte[]` for binary data. A `String` is what you should use. Only protocol organisation will allow all peers to know exactly which types to send and receive without having to type check.